# Проблема с AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob, реклама

Изменил подпись APK c Android debug на свою и перестал получать рекламу от AdMob.(Ошибка 3)

Вернуть подпись без вариантов.

Как доказать AdMob что это я и тоже самое приложение ?

Comment: Я так понял вы изменили имя пакета и перезалили с теми же ID's от AdMob? Старое приложение активно? Связывали приложение с AdMob? А галку поставили в Google Play Console Есть/содержит рекламу?

Comment: Имя пакета не менял. Да с тем же ID баннера. Да старое приложение ещё активно. Привязки к FireBase нет. В Play Markete приложения нет. Я ещё тока учусь и по этому компилировал через Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) и разослал друзьям для теста. Через пару дней появилась платная реклама (без использования addTestDevice) и так проработало месяц пока я не переустановил Android Studio, при установке которой сменилась Debug подпись. А теперь хоть через Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) хоть через Generate Signed Bundle/APK приложение не получает рекламу.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего нужно подождать показа рекламы, подпись не влияет на admob